# constant training validation accuracy problem

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of about 500 .mat files 300 train and 200 test and these are really small sized cropped images that are at most 3kb each. when I try training on the below architecture with the following parameters, I get a test accuracy and loss of 69% and the validation accuracy over 25 epochs remains around 51%. I want to know how to improve my test accuracy and fix the constant validation accuracy problem. 
**note:** The problem is a binary classification problem and the class split is in the 60:40 ratio

```
weight_decay = 1e-3
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),padding='same',input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3),kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
#model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
#model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.50))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['acc'])
es_callback = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)



history= model.fit(#train_generator,
                    X_train,Y_train,
                            batch_size= batch_size,
                            #steps_per_epoch=trainSize,
                            epochs=25,
                            validation_data=(X_val,Y_val),#val_generator,
                            #validation_steps=valSize,
                            #callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)]
                            callbacks=[es_callback]
                            )
```

Comment: how many classes were there ?

Comment: There are 2 classes and the class split is in 60:40 ratio

Comment: try to reduce the dropout before output layer (15-25% max). Dropping half of the features is not a good sign. Also, you need not to use dropout so early inbetween conv layers too. Only if over fitting occurs, it is recommended.